# How to install Un-trusted Certificate (.cer) on iOS Simulator (iOS 7 & above)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, adal

I am working on an iOS app which needs to required to install an Un-trusted certificate on iOS Simulator for testing as I need to connect to ADAL for authentication. I googled a lot but no luck and finally what I did was, I simply drag & drop the certificate into iOS Simulator and tried to install, but it is showing status as "Not Trusted". Can you please help me on how I can achieve it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219707/adding-a-self-signed-certificate-to-iphone-simulator

Comment: @Bushrod, I tried those links but no use. Because they are explaining abut bypass the certificate by adding NSUrlConnetion code.

Comment: The cert could be the issue... not enough bits or signed with insecure algorithm (MD5).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335078/why-is-my-ios-profile-not-trusted  However, I installed a sha1 signed 2048 bit RSA cert (downloaded via iOS Safari in iOS7 simulator), and it also says Not Trusted.

Comment: @Bushrod, Is there anyways to do it? How can I make the certificate as a "Trusted" in iOS simulator?

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to force a cert to be Trusted, but I have had luck using willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge to get past an untrusted one.  Sorry, I know that's not the answer you want.